# question regarding asymptotic runtime behavior

Tags: runtime, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptote

We know that log(n) = O(sqrt n )
I am wondering if is it valid to say  that log(n) is theta( sqrt n )  . 
numerically , i proved that it is right ; yet i am not too sure about it . 
Would like some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log n` is NOT in `Theta(sqrt n)`, since `sqrt n` is asymptotically greater than `log n`, meaning that `log n` isn't in `Omega(sqrt n)`. In other words, `sqrt n` cannot be an asymptotic lower bound for `log n`.

Refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) definition of big theta. Substitute `sqrt n` for `g(n)` and `log n` for `f(n)` in the definition and you will see that you can easily find a `k2` and `n0` such that the definition is satisfied (which is why `log n` is in `O(sqrt n)`), while finding a suitable `k1` will prove impossible (which is why `log n` is NOT in `Omega(sqrt n)`).